# Asymptotics of a logarithmic series

Tags: asymptotics

Given that,

$T(n) = \sum_{i=2}^{n} \log_i n$

I need to find the asymptotic boundary of $T(n)$.

Answer given is $\theta(n)$.
Please provide explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the change-of-base formula may be helpful here:
$$
\log_b(x) = \frac{\ln x}{\ln b}
$$
Also, with sums I always find it helps to write out the sum explicitly, so let's do that:
$$
T(n) = \sum_{i=2}^{n} \log_i n
= \log_2(n) + \log_3(n) + \log_4(n) + \cdots + \log_n(n)
$$

Now if you want to show this is $\theta(n)$, there are two things: you should show it is lower bounded by $cn$, and it is upper bounded by $Cn$, for some constants $c$ and $C$.

- For the lower bound, use the fact that each term is greater than or equal to $1$.
- For the upper bound, I suggest dividing the sum into two parts: from $i = 2$ to $i = \sqrt{n}$, and $i = \sqrt{n}$ to $n$. So the first part is
  $$
  \left(\log_2(n) + \log_3(n) + \log_4(n) + \cdots + \log_{\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor}(n)\right).
  $$
  Here we have $\sqrt{n}$ terms, each which is at most $\log_2(n)$. The second part is
  $$
  \left( \log_{\lceil \sqrt{n} \rceil}(n) + \cdots + \log_n(n) \right).
  $$
  Here we have at most $n$ terms, but you can show (using the change of base formula above) that each term is at most $2$.

Now adding up the two parts, you should get an upper bound of
$$
\sqrt{n} \log_2(n) + 2n,
$$
so the final step is to show this is $O(n)$.

Answer (score 1):

First off, $\log_i n = \ln n / \ln i$, so your sum is:

$\begin{equation*}
  \sum_{2 \le i \le n} \dfrac{\ln n}{\ln i}
    = \ln n \sum_{2 \le i \le n} \dfrac{1}{\ln i}
\end{equation*}$

The last sum has no simple form. We can approximate it as an integral:

$\begin{equation*}
  \sum_{2 \le i \le n} \frac{1}{\ln i}
    \approx \int_2^n \frac{d t}{\ln t}
\end{equation*}$

This is known as the Eulerian logarithmic integral $\operatorname{Li}(n)$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function)), it can be shown that $\operatorname{Li}(n) \sim n / \ln n$ if $n \to \infty$. Thus you get:

$\begin{equation*}
  \sum_{2 \le i \le n} \dfrac{\ln n}{\ln i}
    \sim n
\end{equation*}$

Would need a bit of polish (use integrals to bound the sum from below/above, and use bounds on $\operatorname{Li}(n)$) to make if airtight.

(Here we write $f(n) \sim g(n)$ if $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n) / g(n) = 1$)